# Was it correct to upvote this answer which didn't provide a solution?

Tags: discussion

I recently discovered a rather [severe bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65041832/12287457) in 64-bit VBA and asked about it on Stack Overflow. Because I guess this constitutes a significant and interesting question, it was quickly among the most upvoted unanswered questions of the tag.

Now, a fellow investigator on the subject posted some interesting new insights as [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65259128/12287457) which according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is, of course, a good thing, despite not actually solving the problem. I upvoted the answer because it is "useful" and contributes to the research about the bug.

What I didn't realize was that even without accepting the answer, just by upvoting alone, my question no longer counts as "unanswered" and thus loses potentially important exposure. I did report the issue to Microsoft wherever I could but considering it's VBA, a fix may take a while.

Was it right to upvote in this case? Isn't it counterproductive that such a question doesn't count as "unanswered" anymore?

Edit: To clarify what I mean, the following filter will no longer include my question:

[image: Search Method]

Edit 2: It can be found by searching for `[vba] hasaccepted:no` and sorting by votes but obviously between lots of questions that actually do have a valid answer without a green checkmark. So I guess this is just a limitation of the system we have to live with, since forcing green checkmarks would come with other problems and I know this was already discussed in the past...

Comment: Even if you didn't upvote it, your question would still have a new answer and thus no longer be unanswered.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 if the answer had no upvotes, the question still counts as unanswered. I guess you were right because someone else would have upvoted it soon anyway. This still doesn't solve the problem that questions with non-answers that have upvotes don't count as unanswered anymore, but maybe this compromise must be made, see my comment on the answer to this question...

Comment: I'm not sure exposure on the "unanswered" tab is that useful - I rarely check it for the tags that I follow because the top-scoring questions tend to be unanswerable (for various reasons).  I suspect most regular answerers will have different strategies for finding questions to answer.  So if the answer deserves an upvote, upvote it.  And besides, (almost) anyone can upvote an answer, so it isn't something that you can control.

Comment: @snakecharmerb While I agree that high voted unanswered questions may often be unanswerable for most people, in my opinion that doesn't make them any less interesting, which is why I do check that tab from time to time. Even if these problems can't be solved, it's often important to know they exist. It would have certainly helped me save time when I worked the entire night debugging a VBA project before eventually finding the pitfall. In other situations,not knowing about a bug like this may even be dangerous, eg. when porting an old project to 64-bit, expecting if-statements to work normally.

Comment: This issue I faced multiple times but in other way, recently https://stackoverflow.com/q/63984862/7920473, OP didn’t want to throw his question away from radar.

Comment: Was the answer useful or helpful? That's why it's upvoted, because that what upvoting is for

Comment: Given the amount of reps you got from that question, You could easily start a bounty with the intent of providing more exposure to the bug

Comment: A similar thing [happened to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59601933/is-using-with-statement-with-proxies-a-bad-practice) too...

Comment: @GWD The same thing happened to me with [this VBA bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63989741/bug-when-using-interfaces-on-larger-projects) which is a bit more generic than yours

Comment: @CristianBuse yeah it's an unfortunate limitation of Stack Overflow. I have already seen your post and it scared me away from using interfaces for now ;) I thought about possible solutions for this problem, my best bet would be a filter using the criteria: 1. No accepted answers. 2. Question has more upvotes than answers. I think these two filters combined would be very useful for finding interesting questions but unfortunately, criterion 2 not available and I doubt it will be implemented any time soon...

Comment: @GWD Yeah. And Microsoft fixing the bug is even 'less sooner' :). For this [VBA x64 bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63848617/bug-with-for-each-enumeration-on-x64-custom-classes), I found somewhere on a MS forum that the bug is known at least from 2011, yet still not fixed.

Comment: @CristianBuse haha I think Microsoft doesn't care about VBA anymore... They probably want people to switch to Office Scripts asap

Comment: @GWD I wonder if I were to delete my answer to your question, and then you were to edit the question with the extra cases, would that violate the site policies? And would that make it visible again under search for unaswered?

Comment: @CristianBuse I don't know, but please don't do it. It's your research and you should get the credit/rep. Also, this won't solve the underlying problem... As for visibility, I guess yes, but don't do it!

Comment: @GWD I won't, don't worry. I think it would be a violation. Wish the search would be as expected.

Comment: @CristianBuse, as I added in the question, using the search option `[vba], hasaccepted:no` it is actually possible to look for questions with no green checkmarks (as expected), but there are loads of "answered" and not accepted uninteresting questions among them. Because for almost all of these questions the answer has more upvotes than the question, I suggested that a search option for "Questions with more upvotes than answers" might be useful...

Comment: @GWD Yes, that would be useful. Try ```[vba] hasaccepted:no score:10``` and then sort by newest

Comment: @CristianBuse That works pretty well, thanks!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes. You upvoted a useful answer. That is how SO works *(Should work)*. If you want more exposure place a bounty. People can still filter on no accepted answer. If this is a bug, the real answers are likely to come from Microsoft as most of us can't peek into the innermost workings; only guess from the outside.

---

Here are some of the [help search booleans](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching):

**isaccepted:** yes/true/1 returns only answers that have been marked "accepted"; no/false/0 returns only answers that are not marked accepted.

**hascode**: yes/true/1 returns only posts that contain code blocks; no/false/0 returns only posts that contain no code.

**hasaccepted:** yes/true/1 returns only questions that have accepted answers; no/false/0 returns only questions with no accepted answers.

**isanswered:** yes/true/1 returns only questions that have at least one positively-scored answer; no/false/0 returns only questions with no positively-scored answers.

Comment: I just checked and unfortunately, this is incorrect. If I filter for "no accepted answer" it doesn't show up anymore, because now an answer with upvotes exists. Well, I guess it is that way because otherwise, loads of old questions with unaccepted answers would clutter the search results, so false positives might be unavoidable :/

Comment: It does show up but you are right, it is not easy to find. I had to do vba hasaccepted:no created:2020-11 and then sort on newest and found it on page 2 (and this is in a low volume tag :-( ). Disclaimer, I am not the world's best searcher. Were you to place a bounty, the question could be found within seconds. I looked at searching to find with bounty (hypothetical) rather than use the dedicated tab and ended up with the ugly _vba hasaccepted:0 closed:0 locked:0 hasnotice:1 created:2020-11_  Oof.....

Comment: I don't think a bounty makes sense in this case. I agree that it would give it higher exposure for a week, but most likely nobody will be able to solve the problem. This issue will probably exist for a while before it gets fixed. Also, when you know about it, working around it is not too difficult, so personally, I wouldn't even gain much from a solution. It's people who don't know about it yet who potentially could spare themselves a lot of trouble just by knowing about it in the first place...

Comment: I just noticed you edited your answer, for the record: In my first comment to this answer, we were talking about the "unanswered" tab when browsing a tag. This is equivalent to the "isanswered" boolean and it's probably responsible for 95% of exposure old unanswered questions get.

Comment: Yup. Hence my line indicated the answer will likely come from Microsoft.

Comment: I edited as my filtering on no accepted answer would be via hasaccepted. I was trying to clarify. I agree with you about the unanswered.

Comment: I edited again, I was confused for a bit, turns out I didn't misunderstand the filtering. Check out my updated question where I clarify my search method. I think the other search booleans not used by the GUI are more of theoretical nature, does anyone actually use them?

Comment: I use some of the search booleans. But to be honest, with the low volumes in VBA I usually scroll through last 24-48 hours looking at titles/tag combos. For higher vol e.g. python, I have a pre-set custom filter but still have to manually sort by newest (boo!)

Comment: You think ~180k questions is low volume? 0.o [vba] is... 2 spots away from being on the 1st page of /tags... and there are 1774 pages.

Comment: @TylerH I apologise if I have mispoken. Is the daily volume for VBA that high compared to other tags? I monitor, for example, Python as well, and it seems the volume there is much much higher.

Comment: @QHarr Question frequency might be a different matter altogether (and of course such an old, ancillary tech will pale in comparison to first-class language tags like Python, JavaScript, C#, etc.)... but overall volume-wise, it is pretty high :-)

Comment: ^^ Aha. I meant what you have eloquently differentiated! @TylerH

Comment: But it's _not_ an answer. This is not a forum. It is a Q&A. Please do not encourage such activity.